# Where does my friend live? 8

Tags: wordplay

<sup>*Other questions in this series can be found [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A71693+%22Where+does+my+friend+live%3F%22+is%3Aq).*</sup>

---

One of my friends in my class told me this:

> Roots Vein Alas Upon Bili Kangaroo Chain

**What is he trying to say?**

Comment: This is not the best way to format a series of questions!

Comment: Okay, I have gone through your questions and improved the way you link to the series. This is much more concise, less 'in your face', and means you don't need to update it when you add new puzzles, as the link shows up all puzzles that use your title. Keep using the same wording in the title for any later related puzzles and all will be fine! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest that your friend wants you to:

> arrange *some* of the given words to piece together a sentence which will tell you where he lives.

In this manner it is then possible to construct the phrase:

> (B)**ILI VEIN ALAS KA**(NGAROO)
>
>  or with corrected spacing: **I LIVE IN ALASKA**. The leftover words (ROOTS, UPON and CHAIN) are purely ornamental to make it more difficult for you to find the words that are truly of interest.

Comment: You could say 'I live in China' too...